# dotnet watch removes scripts folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an asp.net project which I run with `dotnet watch` and npm. I run it in Rider but every single time I do this, there are 3 weird changes happening to the project (see image):
[changes seen in git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX51f.png)
It removes two files from the scripts folder and deletes the package.json folder.

The Web.csprosj file includes these lines, so I think its weird that they get removed:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Controller\" />
    <Folder Include="styles\" />
    <Folder Include="scripts\" />
    <Folder Include="ViewModels\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Partials\Svg\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Core\Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Models\Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="scripts\index.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Does anybody know what is going on?